# Get new email with node-imap nodejs

Tags: node.js

I retrieved new email from a gmail account with node-imap. How do I keep a node-worker waiting for any new email and take an immediate action instead of cron jobs?

I don't want to keep hitting the page every few minuets, kind of defeats the purpose of node js.

Here's my code so far

```
var Imap = require('imap'),
inspect = require('util').inspect;

var imap = new Imap({
    user: 'yyyy@gmail.com',
    password: 'xxxx',
    host: 'imap.gmail.com',
    port: 993,
    tls: true,
    tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
});

var fs = require('fs'), fileStream;

function openInbox(cb) {
    imap.openBox('INBOX', false, cb);
}

imap.once('ready', function() {
    openInbox(function(err, box) {
        if (err) throw err;
        imap.search([ 'UNSEEN', ['SINCE', 'October 2, 2013'] ], function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('you are already up to date');
            }
            var f = imap.fetch(results, { bodies: '' });
            f.on('message', function(msg, seqno) {
                console.log('Message #%d', seqno);
                var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
                msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
                    console.log(prefix + 'Body');
                    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('msg-' + seqno + '-body.txt'));
                });
                msg.once('attributes', function(attrs) {
                    console.log(prefix + 'Attributes: %s', inspect(attrs, false, 8));
                });
                msg.once('end', function() {
                    console.log(prefix + 'Finished');
                });
            });
            f.once('error', function(err) {
                console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
            });
            f.once('end', function() {
                console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
            });
        });
    });
});



imap.connect();
```

Answer (score 3):

So, theoretically, you could use the [IMAP IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE) command to do this.

However, it's worth noting several things:

1. `IDLE` will just tell you that new messages have arrived, it won't tell you what those messages are
2. I don't think you can send commands (like search commands) when IMAP is idling, so you may need to create another process to gather the messages somehow.

Another (maybe better) way would be to use some Javascript on the front end to either refresh the page every minute or so, *or* make an AJAX request every minute or so and refresh the message list part of the page. (By "better" I mean simpler. I've done IMAP IDLE implementations before and usually ended up deleting that code because `IDLE` sucked for me.)

If you do go for this polling, client-side or server-side, you probably want to look into [setInterval](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/). (Since this is a Javascript thing in general, not client or Node specific, it'll work wherever).

Comment: Thank you! I found a better solution Mail Listener library https://npmjs.org/package/mail-listener2

Comment: @silvesterprabu can you raise an issue on github if its still not working

Comment: @JackDre: could you please post your sample that worked with mail-listener2?