# Waiting for email to arrive using node-imap

Tags: node.js, imap

I'm using node-imap as a mail solution, but I need a way of waiting until an email arrives.  In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173364/get-new-email-with-node-imap-nodejs) post, someone referenced using the IMAP IDLE command to do this.  I was wondering if anybody has had success with this, and how you would suggest incorporating that into the example code provided in the node-imap readme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decided to go with the [inbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inbox) module. This provides a clear and quick solution through use of the call, `client.on("new", function(message){`.

Answer (score 2):

I think good starting point is to research how is this method created in https://www.npmjs.com/package/inbox#wait-for-new-messages module.

Looks [like this code emits the event](https://github.com/pipedrive/inbox/blob/master/lib/client.js#L1136-L1154) of `new`.
As far as i understood the code of this module, they call the fetch command with intervals

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I may actually look into the inbox module, as it has other functions I need.  I'll update if it works out..

Answer (score 1):

For [node-imap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap), "mail" event will be emitted when new mail arrives in the currently open mailbox.

You can listen to new mail event like this:

```
imap.on('mail', function(numNewMsgs) {
    // Fetch new mail
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to open a mailbox, which you want to listen for new messages. Here an example:

```js
function listerBox() {
  imap.once("error", console.error);
  imap.on("ready", () => {
    imap.openBox("INBOX", true, (error, box) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      
      console.log('Connected!')

      imap.on("mail",  () => {
        console.log("New one!")
      })
    });
  });

  imap.connect();
}

listerBox()
```